# How to know why driver.save_screenshot failed?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

According to the [Python Selenium docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=save_screenshot#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.save_screenshot), `driver.save_screenshot` returns `False` if it encountered an `IOError`. If the save failed, how do I know what the error was?

Example code:

```py
if driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_path):
    print(f"Screenshot saved at {screenshot_path}")
else:
    # Let the devops engineer know why the screenshot couldn't be saved
    print("Screenshot save failed")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method does not let you to know what sort of problem your code encountered when saved a file.

You can implement your own. Use `get_screenshot_as_png()` or `get_screenshot_as_base64()` method, write bytes to the file using standard mechanism and catch possible exceptions.

Comment: Thanks, it seems a little silly to have a function failing silently like that. I'll post my code once I've implemented a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented my own screenshot saver like this:

```py
ss = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
try:
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(screenshot_path), exist_ok=True)
    with open(screenshot_path, "wb") as ss_file:
        ss_file.write(ss)
        print(f"Screenshot saved at {screenshot_path}")
except Exception as err:
    print(f"Screenshot save failed with {type(err).__name__}: {err}")
```